# How to open ports number from 32768-65334 on ubuntu?

Tags: networking, server, port-forwarding, lxd

I have to open those ports for clearwater ims. They will be used for SNMP.

Comment: They might not be blocked.

Comment: No, They are not working. I have to open all ports, one by one....

Comment: IS there any shortcut by that I can open all those ports altogether?

Comment: I am using command ufw allow port-no/tcp. ufw allow port-no-start:port-no-end/tcp, it didn't work for me.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "open ports"? Do you want to open a network socket listening on the port? Do you want to configure a firewall to accept incoming connections on them? Do you want to configure port forwarding on a NAT router? Please [edit] your question when you want to clarify something or add information. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Read `man ufw`. You can only open 1 port at at time. If you MUST open all those ports (and can't constrain the port range) use `seq` (`man seq`):

```
for p in $( seq 32768 65534 ) ; do  
    ufw allow $p/tcp  
done
```